# An application with PySide2 and Pyinstaller generates a 192MB file in Linux but 70 mb on windows

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller, pyside2

I'm making a stand alone PySide2 application with PyInstaller, but the file size is huge on Linux, in windows the .exe size is just 70mb while in Linux is 192MB

In both cases the build was made using a virtual environment only with the necessary modules. Looks like the problem is PySide2, since a tiny window with a label produce a 129.3 MB file. Does anyone knows how to address this problem?

This is a MWE for which pyinstaller produces a 129.3 MB:

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

# Create a Qt application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a Label and show it
label = QLabel("Hello World")
label.show()
# Enter Qt application main loop
app.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

> info:
>
> windows 10
>
> linux mint 19.2
>
> python 3.7.5 64 bits on linux
>
> python 3.7.4 32 bits on windows
>
> pyinstaller: 4.0.dev0+a9b299995
>
> PySide2: 5.13.0
>
> command: ../venv/bin/pyinstaller --onefile mwe.py

### Edit 1:

I checked the size of pyside2 in both Windows and Linux, and it is much heavier in Linux, more than 450 mb while in Windows it is only 300 Mb

Comment: If you compile for windows **64bit** what's the size? 64bit executables are naturally larger, significantly so at times. Although a +174% increase in size seems weird.

Comment: @Bakuriu 88.9 MB no that much of increase

Comment: If you run pyinstaller in the mode where to creates a directory will all the files, instead of a single bundled executable file, you should be able to inspect it file by file or directory by directory, which will at least tell you what files are bigger, or present in addition on the Linux output. That should get you at least partways to an answer to your question.